# How to make my Ubuntu not connect to any porn websites for my kids?

Tags: internet

I want to block all porn sites regardless of language or location. How can I do this?

I changed my `/etc/hosts` to do stuff like:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts|tail
127.0.0.1   xxx.com
127.0.0.1   badharampictures.net
```

But is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Use MoralDNS (https://github.com/RoelVdP/MoralDNS). Full disclosure; I am am the maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy and great way of doing it is going straight to the source and use DNS filtering for that purpose.

https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home/

Setup an account, make the changes in your router to use the DNS servers from OpenDNS, activate parental filtering and no matter what OS your kids are using that obtain an IP via the router will be blocked from accessing issue sites.

Of course if your kids are smart enough and know how to spoof that it will be easy for them to bypass it, that again, as said before, you wont be able to protect your children all the time from all the dangers the internet presents.

Answer (score 0):

OpenDNS Family Shield may be the easiest solution. Just change your DNS settings to point to 208.67.222.123

Also, there are multiple others. [Click here to take a look.](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-block-pornographic-websites-without-spending-money-on-software/)